# Why is Pokemon go not working?

Tags: pokemon-go, technical-issues, ios

Pokemon Go opens perfectly and starts up just fine on my iPad Air which DOESN'T have cellular data. I read the App store page for it and it said it was compatible with iPad. But after it loads, it says "no GPS connection" because of my layered roof, so I go outside.

It then stops saying no GPS connection, but then says no internet connection. I can walk around with it saying no internet, but the game doesn't start without internet, and I've read online that Pokemon don't spawn without internet. So I really can't play the game on iPad. No, I can't get cellular data, or any kind of portable router. Is there something I don't know that I could do?

Comment: You need both data and GPS to play the game. So it sounds like it's not going to work in your case.

Answer (score 5):

The game (Pokemon Go) needs cellular data or any other kind of internet since most of the game is played outside.  One of the bigger points to the game is visiting PokeStops (to get prizes and bonuses) and Pokemon Gyms.

The iPad Air is supported since they're versions of it with Cellular data access.  You could take your iPad with you, and find a PokeStop with wifi near by if you wish to continue playing in your current setup. (Or use a hotspot on your phone if you have that option).

Answer (score 0):

You should be able to use Free Wifi, it should work over that.

Also, make sure location services are enabled. That could have something to do with the "No GPS connection" message.

Comment: "Use free WiFi" doesn't really solve the problem, and he said that the GPS didn't work because of his house.